# If the global dimension is equal to the krull dimension of a ring R, then R is regular

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, krull-dimension, regular-rings

Let R be a (non local) noetherian ring, and let $\mathrm{gldim}(R)$ be the global dimension. Recall that R is *regular* iff for every maximal ideal $m\subset R$ the localization $R_m$ is regular.

If $R$ has finite Krull dimension, then we have the following equivalence:

> $R$ is regular iff $\mathrm{gldim}(R)=\dim(R)$.

But does this also hold for infinite dimensional rings? To be more precise i know that the implication "$\Rightarrow$" is true, but what about "$\Leftarrow$"?

Comment: What do you mean by $\dim R=\operatorname{gldim}R$ when Krull dimension is not finite?

Comment: I define the global dimension by taking the supremum of all projective dimensions, i.e. $gl\colon dim(R) = sup${$pd(M)\mid$ M is an R-module.}

Comment: Ah wait i think i know what you mean. I am basically asking: if $gldim(R)=\infty$, then R is regular.... Yeah I think thats certainly not true